# No suggestions TextBox.AutoComplete

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to use the AutoComplete properties to get a textbox with suggestions but the current code doesn't work

```
private void MainForm_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = global.sellableItems;

        AutoCompleteStringCollection myCustomStringCollect = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        myCustomStringCollect.AddRange(new string[]{"Facet Hatchet",
                "Facet Fishing Rod",
                "Facet Hat of Crafting",
                "Facet Coat of Crafting",
                "Facet Gloves of Crafting",
                "Facet Trousers of Crafting",
                "Facet Boots of Crafting",
                "Facet Cap of Gathering",
                "Facet Coat of Gathering",
                "Facet Fingerless Gloves of Gathering",
                "Facet Bottoms of Gathering",
                "Facet Boots of Gathering"});
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myCustomStringCollect;
    }
```

Once it compiled, i try it but it doesn't work.

[image: Image of the textbox not suggesting anything]

Comment: I copy-paste your snippet and it works fine on .Net 4.6.1. You may need to find if there is another place changing your text box.

Comment: Why do you have a `Load()` handler named `MainForm_Load_1`? Do you have more than one? Are you sure this is the one that is actually called? Why do you have Visual Styles off?

Comment: Sorry @Jimi i just renamed some to be more understandable. I'm sure it's the one that is called. Visual Styles ?

Comment: @LouisGo ... I don't know what to say. Maybe it's not related to the code so.

Comment: Made a minimal form to test it on your production .Net framework. If it's working, then your codebase has other issues. If it's not working, it could be a .Net framework bug. However I assume it's probably the first case.

Comment: Are you sure because you put a breakpoint there and you have verified that the code reaches the `.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myCustomStringCollect` line? It would work otherwise.  If an exception is raised the Load event, there's not notification, the code simply *jumps* off of it. Also check whether you have more than one `Load` handler. -- You `Add Item` Button and the TextBox Border and shadow show that your app doesn't set `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` in `program.cs` (it's not directly related, the VisualStyles status does not compromise the TextBox Autocomplete mode).

Comment: But, if the Visual Styles disabled status is not intentional, there might be something else that is wrong somewhere else. This cannot be determined by the code you posted or the description of the problem itself. Anyway, it looks like this code is not executed or the TextBox you're looking at is not the *expected* `textBox1` (it happens when you `new()` a Form class that is not the one that is currently shown.).